I uninstall Ubuntu, but it´s still showing in the dual boot
When the PC starts, it tries to boot Ubuntu, but fails. How can I resolve this?
I used bcdedit to delete Ubuntu. Now the command show me this.


Before deleting Ubuntu (if your system was dual boot), you need to ensure your wanted OS controls the booting process. If you've deleted Ubuntu, you need to fix your issue using Windows (or whatever OS you have installed) repair media; windows versions have commands for this.
